# If condition doesn't trigger

Tags: twitter, oauth, bots, tweepy, markov

Long story short story, I am playing with the tweepy library to make a markov bot on twitter: I am now trying to answer to the right tweet but...

```
>>> repr(mention.id)
'698147667990441984'                                                            
>>> repr(698147667990441984)                                    
'698147667990441984'                                                            
>>> mention.id is 698147667990441984                                    
False                                                                           
>>>
```

The ID of the targeted tweet (I am currently working with a hardcoded tweet) has this exact ID but for some reason any check leads to a 'False' no matter how I do it (for instance by trying to convert it into strings)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The tweet ID is most probably a string. So just put it between quotation marks: `mention.id is '698147667990441984'`